# linux + how to download the json2csv tool

Tags: linux, yum, wget, curl, download

we have redhat linux

how to download and install the json2csv tool by yum ( which repository )

or by curl/wget from    https://github.com/korczis/json2csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the repository using [`git clone`](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/):

```
git clone https://github.com/korczis/json2csv.git
```

There is even a button "Clone or download" which lets you to download the project as ZIP.

In case you need to [search](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum) for NAME in your YUM repository packages:

```
yum search NAME
```

which will return matches in package names or descriptions.